# Disable contextual Action bar in android webview on text selection

Tags: android, android-webview, contextual-action-bar

How to disable contextual action bar in web view?   I Want text selection feature to remain as it is , but i don't want the Contextual action bar to come, how can i disable it ?

[image]

Using this code hides the  contextual  action bar but it is looking bad(whole screen is shaking ) and also text selection is not retaining.

```
    @Override
    public void onSupportActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    super.onSupportActionModeStarted(mode);
    mode.finish();
   }
```

How can i disable the contextual actionbar ? Is there any other way?

Comment: did you find the solution yet?

Comment: @WaleedAsim didn't find the solution

Comment: i just found the solution with api level >=23 but i want in api level < 23

Comment: I think that action bar shows only on api <23

Comment: yes but in api level >=23 we can hide menu popup but in how to hide it in api level <23

Comment: I couldn't find the solution at all and gave up on it , While searching for it i can across a library for text selection give it a try

Comment: can you send me the link of library?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176210/discussion-between-waleed-asim-and-redman).

Answer (score 2):

I know it is late to answer question but i just found it and it works fine.(I tested it on 5.0.1 and it works fine)(Following code will only clear copy , paste and select all option from menu.)

inject folliwing code in your html code which you will be loading in webview,

```
"<script src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js\"></script>\n" +
 "<script>\n" +
            "$(function() {\n" +
            "  $(document.body).bind('touchstart', function(e) {\n" +
            "    var selection;\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    if (window.getSelection) {\n" +
            "      selection = window.getSelection();\n" +
            "    } else if (document.selection) {\n" +
            "      selection = document.selection.createRange();\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "\n" +
            "    selection.toString() !== '' && ReaderJavaScript.onTextselectionEnded(true)\n" +
            "  });\n" +
            "});\n" +
            "</script>"
```

---

see in code i used ReaderJavaScript interface which will act as bridge between js code and activity to carry information on call of ReaderJavaScript.onTextselectionEnded(true).
so whenever user end selection it will indicate and at that time you just have to add following code to clear menus in your activity,

```
 readerView.setTextSelectionFinishedListener(new ReaderView.TextSelectionFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTextSelectionEnded(boolean textSelectionEnded) {
                if (mActionMode != null){
                    if (mActionMode.getMenu() != null){
                        mActionMode.getMenu().clear();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove it manually.

When the legacy action mode bar is triggered, the view hierachy would be:

[image: view hierachy]

So just **fix the unwanted hierachy** by the following code:

```
View p2th = Utils.getNthParent(root, 2);
if (p2th!=null && p2th.getId()==R.id.action_bar_root) {
    Utils.replaceView(Utils.getNthParent(root, 1), p2th);
}
```

where `Utils.getNthParent` returns N-th parent of the root view, and `Utils.replaceView` just replace the action bar root with our content view .

(tested on android 4.4 and 5 sucessfully, without flicker or crash.)

What a genius solution, so simple and so stupid……